# Ruby gem build (with executable) shows Warning: bin/some_cmd is not executable

Tags: ruby, rubygems

Why do I get this warning when building a ruby gem that has an executable? However, when I install the gem, the executable works perfectly.

```
$ gem build mygem.gemspec
$ gem install mygem-0.1.0.gem
WARNING:  bin/rdiag is not executable
$ rdiag
===> WORKS FINE!!!
```

Why do I get the warning? I've created gems before and don't recall seeing this warning.

Comment: You need to supply a *lot* more detail to have any hope of someone being able to help you here.

Answer (score 2):

For me, this was because the file was never set as executable. If you're working in a bash terminal you can run:

`chmod ugo+x bin/rdiag`

Then, next time you run the build command you will no longer see the warning. It is just a warning though, not a build-breaker.